# Error: HTML onClick not defined with Node.js, NPM and Parcel

Tags: javascript, node.js, input, npm, parceljs

I am making a weather application.

To develop this I am using Node.js with NPM and Parcel. (I need to do this, because otherwise OpenLayers won't work, but I have not worked with it before.)

I need to be able to work with user-input. For example I want the user to click on a button and then something needs to happen.

Below a very simple explanation what I need to accomplish.

The button, which I need to be in the index.html

```
<input type="button" name="bt" value="test" onclick="clickKnop()">
```

Function that needs to be executed after click, which I need to be in the index.js

```
    function clickKnop(){
        console.log('Hello World'); 
    };
```

Of course in my application the function needs to be different, but that is not my problem.

When I am coding in the Node.js environment it works ONLY when I put the clickKnop function in the script part of my HTML.

When I put the function in my index.js file, it doesn't work anymore. I get the following error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: clickKnop is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick**

This also happens when I use the created /dist files on my server on which they will be presented once the application is finished.

How can I make this work?

Hope you guys can help!!

EDIT:

```js
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
import TileWMS from 'ol/source/TileWMS.js';
import {fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj';
import {ZoomSlider} from 'ol/control.js';

 /*
  Hieronder komt het stukje code voor de datum en tijd.
  Default moet present datetime zijn, afgerond op 10 min (naar beneden).
  Vervolgens moeten er stapjes van 10 minuten terug gemaakt worden om uit te kiezen.
  De eindgebruiker moet zelf ook een datetime in kunnen voeren welke dan opgehaald wordt.
  Hiervoor worden ook de stapjes van 10 minuten gebruikt.
 */

 // Current datetime
 const date = new Date();
 
 //Round current datetime to last 10 min
 const coeff = 1000 * 60 * 10;
 const floorDate = new Date(Math.floor(date.getTime() / coeff) * coeff);

 //Format the current datetime so that it can be used as input for the WMS viewparams
 const floorDateFormat = new Date(floorDate.toString().split('GMT')[0]+' UTC').toISOString().split('.')[0].replace('T',' ');
 
 console.log(floorDateFormat);
 
 
 // -10 minutes from current time + formatting for input viewparams
 const minusTenMinutes = floorDate;
 minusTenMinutes.setMinutes(minusTenMinutes.getMinutes() - 10);
 const minusTenMinutesFormat = new Date(minusTenMinutes.toString().split('GMT')[0]+' UTC').toISOString().split('.')[0].replace('T',' ');
 
 console.log(minusTenMinutesFormat);
 console.log(floorDate);


 /*
  Hieronder wordt de map gemaakt.
  De verschillende layers en layergroepen worden aangeroepen.
  De viewparams + datetime moet mee gaan met de hierboven gedefinieerde datetime
  Daarnaast moet de gebruiker ook kunnen wisselen tussen de verschillende weersoorten,
  hiervoor moeten de params geüpdatet worden.
 */
 let datetime = "2018-10-16 08:00:00";
 
 //Base Europe
 const wmsSourceBaseLayer = new TileWMS({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/O/wms',
      params: {
        'LAYERS': 'O:Europe_Polygons',
        'TILED': true
      },
      serverType: 'geoserver',
      crossOrigin: ''
    });

    const wmsBaseLayer = new TileLayer({
      source: wmsSourceBaseLayer
    });
 
 //Weather || DEFAULT TEMPERATURE
 const wmsSourceTemperature = new TileWMS ({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/O/wms',
      params: {
        'LAYERS': 'O:Temperature',
        'TILED': true,
  'viewparams': 'chosen_timestamp:' + datetime
      },
      serverType: 'geoserver',
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    });
 
 const wmsWeatherLayer = new TileLayer({
  source: wmsSourceTemperature
 });

 //Update de params zodat er ander weer komt
 //wmsSourceTemperature.updateParams({'LAYERS': 'Observations:observations_v'});
 
 //LonLat of germany converted for use in view
 const germanyLonLat = [10.018343, 51.133481];
 const germanyConvertedLonLat = fromLonLat(germanyLonLat);
 
 //Making a view for the map
    const view = new View({
      center: germanyConvertedLonLat,
      zoom: 5
    });
 
 //Building the map with the layers
    const map = new Map({
      layers: [wmsBaseLayer, wmsWeatherLayer],
      target: 'map',
      view: view
    });
 
  
  
  
  
 function clickKnop(){
  console.log('Hello World'); 
 };
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Tiled WMS</title>
  <!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"/>-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <style>
    #map {
      width: 450px;
      height: 500px;
   border: 3px solid grey;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
  <input type="button" name="bt" value="test" onclick="clickKnop()">
</body>
```

Now it is kind of a mess, but what I want to accomplish is that the different geoserver WMS-layer gets called with different params depending on time.

To do this I want input from my HTML (and I also want to make a button to go back in steps of 10 minutes).

So I want to make functions that call the WMS-layers that change the time variable.

Again, the code that I have now is really messy, but I am still working on it, so please look past that..

Hope this helps...

Comment: its a scoping issue, do you have the `clickKnop()` function definition within the EventListener definition or something? Include the  `.js` file so we can help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43209534/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-at-htmlinputelement-onclick - it's possible you're not closing your script tag in the template file. Also if possible post full code in context

Comment: I will add my code! Give me a minute

Comment: I saw that the project.1234.js that is generated by node.js npm and parcel gives different names to functions and variables. Could that be part of the problem? (Or maybe that has nothing to do with it.)

Comment: ok. why not just place the script inside of the body tag?

Comment: Because I need to import a lot of things in my JavaScript-file, that I can't do in my HTML, and the input needs to make changes in my JavaScript

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is of good quality, but I've included an answer that may point you in the right direction of getting starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you have confused the difference between frontend and backend scripting.

You will have to develop a frontend application that will be able to talk to your node.js application. Your HTML code cannot read the NodeJS source code and that's why you're getting the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: clickKnop is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick`.

By the looks of it, you will have to separate out your frontend code to call endpoints on your NodeJS application using something like https://expressjs.com/.

An example of this would be:

**Frontend** using JQuery

```
<body>
<a id="UpdateMap">Update Map</a>
<script src="jquery..." />
<script>
    $('#UpdateMap').click(function(){
       $.get( "myNodeJSServer:Port/UpdateMap", function( data ) {
          $( ".map" ).html( data );
          alert( "Load was performed." );
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

**Backend** using Express and NodeJS

```
...
//In your NodeJS Express Routes Application Page
app.get('/UpdateMap', function (req, res) {
  clickKnop();
})
```

Comment: I quite new to the webdevelopment this way, so you are probably right that I don't really understand the concepts fully yet. But may I ask you one more thing? Now I am developing the app using Node.js, but in the end I want it to be displayed on my Tomcat server. I am doing this by: npm run build and then copy the dist files from my project to a Tomcat webapps (/dist) map. Does you answer still apply then? Or does it work different?

Comment: You can easily create your own web server using NodeJS and **not** using Apache Tomcat. (Which is the way I'd approach your problem). If you create a NodeJS application using Express (Follow their getting started tutorials), you can goto your browser `http://localhost:8080/` and call your NodeJS Application. 

You wouldn't be copying files between NodeJS and Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I spend my whole morning watching tutorials of Express. The reason I copied my dist files to my Tomcat server was because the OL5 setup guide tells me to do this. (Or at least, copy the files to a server and I am using the Tomcat server already for GeoServer, so that seemed the best solution.) I am looking into making the app with Express, but not sure if this is necessary. (The link to setup guide: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html)

Comment: Oh, I see the culprit now. That line refers to coping the dist/ folder to your `NodeJS` server from your development machine when you're ready for deploying to the application. As a Dev, you don't have to do this and keep your server on your local machine until your finished. Then you can look into how to distribute your code.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. But I still don't really get why it doesn't work with just the html and javascript. Because I found this example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/animation.html. This has buttons and uses .getElementByID. I am mostly confused I think why it does work there... Because the function does not work in my dev environment either. (Only when I put it in the script tag in my HTML)

Comment: That example doesn't actually use NodeJS at all. This is going out of the scope of your origional question but here's a quick example I found of OpenLayers used in Native Javascript (and JQuery) that doesn't require NodeJS. (http://jsfiddle.net/VictorVelarde/DbCgt/).

Comment: Thanks Dean. I am very grateful for all you answers. I will look into this example, and then I will decide if I have to work with Express or this. And sorry for all the questions, but for someone that is new to this it isn't really clear. Because the examples don't seem to work as they show and I cannot find a clear explanation anywhere on the internet that helps me understand how I am supposed to make my OL5 app. So thanks for all the help!